# How to use multibyte characters with postgresql trigram module?

Tags: postgresql

I use trigram string comparison in posgtresql (CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;). But when I try to insert into a table with trigram index a string with a multibyte character ('' for example) it fails with error SQL state: 22021 invalid multibyte character for locale.

```
create table tg_mb(
string_mb character varying (1)
);

CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_mb
ON tg_mb
USING gist
(string_mb COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gist_trgm_ops);

insert into tg_mb values ('');
```

The question is - how to transform a characters in a string so they fit into a table or better to strip them off the string at all? Tried to find an answer, but read that trigram supports multibyte characters. All examples are about letters. The pictograph has longer length.

Comment: Which is your locale?

Comment: @Renzo
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'